# Layer boarder not showing at top and right edge of view and UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiview, ios7, xamarin.ios

I use below codes in order to adding borders to `UIView` and also border to an `UITableView`.

for `UIView`:

```
RectangleF _frame = new RectangleF (0, 0, this.Frame.Width , 56);
                DescriptionView = new UIView (_frame);
                DescriptionView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.White  ;
                DescriptionView.Layer.BorderColor = new CGColor (0, 0, 0, 1.0f);
                DescriptionView.Layer.BorderWidth = 0.5f;
```

For `UITable`:

```
RectangleF _frame = new RectangleF (0, DescriptionView.Frame.Height + 10,
                this.Frame.Width , this.Frame.Height - (DescriptionView.Frame.Height + 10));
            InstructionTable = new UITableView (_frame);
            InstructionTable.Layer.BorderColor = new CGColor (0, 0, 0, 1.0f);
            InstructionTable.Layer.BorderWidth = 0.5f;
```

for iPhone 3.5 inch and iPhone 4inch it works fine but for iPad the border is not showing on right of the view and also on top and right of the table. See below screen shot:

[image]

Comment: Does any one see this problem before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
DescriptionView.Layer.BorderWidth = 0.5f;
```

I used grater width:

```
DescriptionView.Layer.BorderWidth = 1f;
```

and it fixed my problem